# What is the minimum I need to import to use bootstrap-grid in version 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, yarnpkg

I downloaded the source of bootstrap into my application using yarn

```
yarn install boostrap
```

I tried just importing the bootstrap-grid.css in my application, and when I copied the starter example the look had no grid layout style applied to it.

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/pricing/

When I added the entire boostrap.css it worked fine.

So what else other than bootstrap-grid should I be importing to get the layout/grid components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pricing example uses card-deck and cards, not the grid.

If you want cards, you need to use `bootstrap.css`. `bootstrap-grid.css` works specifically for the [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

Comment: I included just bootstrap-grid, and I don't see flex-column in their either.  That is part of the grid right?

Comment: but that utilitiy class is included in the bootstrap-grid.scss file so it should be in the .css file no? https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss

Comment: Yes, the utils are there.. but i also see them in the .css https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css

Answer (score 0):

The below files worked for me. I am not sure if this is documented anywhere.

```
functions.scss
variables.scss
mixins.scss
reboot.scss
_grid.scss
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer from triplethreat23, you should also import the `$grid-gutter-width` variable so that you will be able to set a gutter on your project's grid if needed.
There are other variables that you may want to set up that the grid system is using, for them please refer to the official documentation and you should be able to add them like the following example:

```
/*------------------------------------*\
    Grid gutter
\*------------------------------------*/
$grid-gutter-width: 0 !default;

/*------------------------------------*\
    Bootstrap file imports
\*------------------------------------*/
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/grid";
```